# get everyvalue of more than one option

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Code

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only">Address : </label>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="fulladdress" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Address" required="required" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Shipping : </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="shipping" name="shipping">
        <option  value=""></option>
        <option  value="DHL">DHL</option>
        <option  value="HDL">HDL</option>
    </select>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="right: 10px;bottom: 10px;position: absolute"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Payment : </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="bank" name="payment">
        <option  value=""></option>
        <option value="btc">Bitcoin</option>
        <option value="pp">PayPal</option>
    </select>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="right: 10px;bottom: 10px;position: absolute"></i>
    </div>
<div class="btn">
    <button id="abc" type="button" href="">ORDER NOW!</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var sel = document.getElementsByClassName("form-group");
sel.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("abc").href = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=6281911090008&text=" + this.value + ".html";
}
```

I want to make "value" when user click button "ORDER NOW" into a link whatsapp API like https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=numberphone&text=(value)

Example : https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=numberphone&text=Full%20Address%20:%20Sir%20Matt%20Busby%20Way%20Shipping%20:%20DHL%20Payment%20:%20PayPal

I have tried several ways to get "value" from select option but didnt work

Comment: You can't assign an event handler to a collection of elements like that.  You have to iterate through sel and apply the handler to each select individually.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the values of `<select>` elements in variables, then reference those variables in the URL

Using jQuery:

```
$('#abc').click(function() {
   var adr = document.getElementById('address').value;
   var option1 = document.getElementById('shipping').value;
   var option2 = document.getElementById('bank').value;
   window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=numberphone&text=Address%3A%20' + adr + '%0AShipping%3A%20' + option1 + '%0ABank%3A%20' + option2 + '%2E');
});
```

Native JavaScript:

```
var sendText = function() {
   var adr = document.getElementById('address').value;
   var option1 = document.getElementById('shipping').value;
   var option2 = document.getElementById('bank').value;
   window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=numberphone&text=Address%3A%20' + adr + '%0AShipping%3A%20' + option1 + '%0ABank%3A%20' + option2 + '%2E');
}
```

For native JS also add onclick function to your button HTML:

```
<button id="abc" type="button" href="" onclick="sendText()">ORDER NOW!</button>
```

Here's a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xo99zrLe/